# Question about proof of second mean value theorem for integrals.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

I am reading about second mean value theorem and have questions about some parts of the proof

Here
$f$ is decreasing and positive function on $[a,b]$ and $g$ is integrable on $[a,b]$

$p=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\int_{x_i}^{x_{i+1}}[f(x)-f(x_i)]g(x)dx$

Author says because $g$ is bounded $|g(x)|\leq L$

Therefore

$|p|$ $\leq$ $\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\int_{x_i}^{x_{i+1}}|f(x)-f(x_i)||g(x)|dx$ $\leq$$L\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}w_i(f)\Delta x_i$

where $w_i(f)$ is oscilation of function on $i$-th interval.

Can you in detail explain how last inequality is derived?

Comment: Did you forget an $L$ in your last inequality?

Comment: @LeeMosher Yes thanks for correction.

Comment: Also, let me say that this does not look anything like the proof of the [Intermediate Value Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_value_theorem). Are you sure that you are not reading about the proof of some other theorem?

Comment: @LeeMosher Book is not in english but it's called intermediate value theorem(Bone)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recall the definition of the oscillation of $f$ on an interval and its equivalent form

$$\omega_i(f) := \sup_{t\in [x_i,x_{i+1}]}f(t) - \inf_{t\in [x_i,x_{i+1}]}f(t) = \sup_{s,t\in [x_i,x_{i+1}]}|f(s) - f(t)|,$$

Thus, $|f(x) - f(x_i)| \leqslant \omega_i(f)$ for all $x \in [x_i,x_{i+1}]$, and

$$\int_{x_i}^{x_{i+1}}|f(x)-f(x_i)| \, dx \leqslant \omega_i(f)(x_{i+1}-x_i)= \omega_i(f) \Delta x_i$$

That along with $|g(x)| \leqslant L$ yields your last inequality.

Comment: thank you.If we have that $mf(a) \leq \int_a ^b f(x)g(x)dx \leq Mf(a)$ why from this follows that there exists $c \in [m,M]$ s.t. $I$(integral) = $cf(a)$.I know IVT but can't conclude from that

Comment: @unit1991: I was addressing your actual question.  You are now raising a different question.

Comment: Sorry I thought answer of second question would be short,and you could answer in the comments

Comment: @unit1991: OK I see what you mean by the "second mean value theorem ".

Comment: It should be that if $g$ is integrable and $f$ is decreasing then there exists $c$ such that $\int_a^b f(x) g(x) \, dx = f(a)\int_a^c g(x) \, dx$.

Comment: Yes that's second mean value theorem.

Comment: @unit1991: [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2371497/148510) is one way to prove it by converting to a Riemann-Stieltjes integral.  I think you also want to do it with Riemann sums. That is shown [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1442335/148510). This is also called Bonnet's theorem.

Comment: Yep @RRL I don't know about RIemann-Stieltijes integral yet.

Comment: OK look at the second approach.